# How many HDDs can I put in an IBM 3450 server?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, ibm-server

I have this [IBM 3450 Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?subtype=ca&infotype=an&appname=iSource&supplier=897&letternum=ENUS108-381). It says:

> Up to 1.5 TB3 SATA disk storage

There are three 3.5 inch bays. One is having a 500GB SATA and other two are empty. Now I want to ask if I can put a 3TB SATA in those bays or can't I use more than 1.5TB? Secondly, is it possible to put a DVD drive in one of those bays. A standard drive would be to big, but are there smaller drives for servers like this?

Comment: You cannot use a 3TB because one of two issues. First the SATA controller does not support it and more then likely your dealing with a non-UEFI BIOS. I see no reason not to connect a SATA disk drive. Your question shows very little research to be honest.  But the server already has a "DVD Drive Bay" just use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the server was released they probably didn't have certified drives larger than 500GB to offer; 3 bays x 500GB = 1.5TB.

You can use larger drives, but as Ramhound points out, you'll want to ensure the BIOS and HDD controller can handle drives >2TB before buying a bunch of drives with that capacity. :)

There's no such thing as a 3.5" DVD drive, as a DVD couldn't physically fit in that space (DVD = 12CM = 4.7").

Comment: what does Ramhound mean that server has DVD bay as  you r right in saying that 4.7" can't fit in 3.5". server is 1U. how can i find that how much max drivee it can support

Comment: Looking at this picture: http://www.geeks.com/largePic_all.asp?invtid=X3450-XEON30X2-PB-R&pic=X3450-XEON30X2-PB-R-box.jpg  I can see that there is a DVD drive top left above the 3.5 drive bay.

Comment: However the DVD bay may not have the drive installed accoding to the IBM spec: http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=migr-5074422

Comment: @Soren no its not there. also the description says it has 2 3.5 inch bays. but actually there are three. unless i use laptop dvd drive like lenevo has

Comment: @user19340357 You would use a laptop/notebook style DVD drive in that spot, but you'll probably need a proprietary mounting bracket and special cabling to implement it as IBM intended.